# Save to var content of two tags

Tags: php, html, xml, variables, tags

In php you can extract the content between two tags html, xml or similar.

Example, if I have.

```
<div><h1>Title </h1><table><tr><td> Data 1 </td><td> Data 2 </td></tr></table></div>
```

I can save in variable and show with echo

```
 <h1> Title <h1><table><tr><td> Data 1 </td><td> Data 2 </td></tr></table>
```

I've made ​​this example and it gives me error.

> $ html = "Hello `<p><b>how are you</b></p>`";

```
$ dom = new DOMDocument ('1 .0 ',' utf-8 ');
$ dom-> loadHTML ($ html);
$ dom-> preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$ htwo = $ dom-> getElementsByTagName('div');
echo $ htwo-> item (0) -> nodeValue;
```

I shows

```
<p> <b> Hello how are you </ b> </ p>
```

but

```
Hello how are you
```

How do I do it? and if is xml tag??

thank you very much

Comment: Can you define "error"? And the spaces between $ and dom are a copy->paste thing? Or are they like that in your code?

Comment: dude, with all those spaces does your code even work?

Answer (score 0):

`nodeValue` is just the text content of the node. To get the HTML content, use:

```
$dom->saveHTML($htwo->item(0));
```

[Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that it is a 'best effort' parser, and your 'HTML' is little more than a fragment. It expects a whole HTML document.

Provide a more complete HTML fragment i.e:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>Your Text Here</body>
</html>
```

and it will do a better job.